# Uncomment and comment a line of config file using sed in linux

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am having the below text in my-config file

```
<!--<URL>www.abc.com</URL>-->
         www.xyz.com
```

I want to uncomment the commented line and comment the uncommented line. I tried using the sed command

```
 sed -i '/<!--<URL>www.abc.com</URL>-->/s/^#//g' filename
```

but getting error as

`sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command:`/'`

please help in resolving this or correct if anything wrong in my sed command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What commented line? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the '/' as the sed delimiter, you must escape '\' the '/' in the  tag.

e.g.

```
 sed -i '/<!--<URL>www.abc.com<\/URL>-->/s/^#//g' filename
```

You can also switch your delimiter in sed for better readability [more](https://coderwall.com/p/khdkuw/delimiters-in-sed-substitution).

Comment: Same situation. When you have characters that match your delimiter you must escape them or choose an alternate delimiter.

Comment: It takes more than escaping delimiters. See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed). In the OPs case all those `.`s would need to be escaped too. The correct solution when you want to search for a string instead of a regexp is to just use awk since it understands strings.